Mathematical Description of Lidar Scan Pattern
I was going through Lidar sensors and their scan patterns and I saw this one:

It is the scan pattern of a Lidar called Livox Horizon but it can be seen in oder Lidar models too.
I want to model these Lidar, and I am wondering what is the mathematical description of this pattern or how to implement it in a program.

you'd best contact the manufacturers. they'll know how they wiggle their lasers to do those things. those patterns are probably proprietary (differing between mfgs), probably differ by sensor model, not to mention production variations causing differences between sensors of the same model... and the same sensor depending on environmental conditions. you might not be able to rely on the sensor tracing those patterns exactly, but it should exactly tell you where it did sample.

The plot shows the angles the laser beam is deflected horizontally and vertically integrated over time.  If those angles are θ and φ, and time is t, then a model for the scan pattern will have the form:
θ = f(t)
φ = g(t)
I'll assume the beam bounces off a reflector mounted to a pan-tilt mechanism (like a galvanometer) that can turn the reflector side to side (θ) and up and down (φ).
If f and g are sine waves (or combinations of sine waves), you can produce all sorts of scanning patterns by adjusting their amplitudes and frequencies.
Looking through various sources online, it appears the device starts out with the kind of flower-like pattern you'd get from a Spirograph toy.

Livox calls their scanning pattern "non-repeating".  I think that means that the frequencies of f and g are relatively prime.  So, although each is repeating, those periods don't ever align (or at least, not in a practicably short amount of time).  In the flower pattern shown above, you can see where the scan started and stopped.  Each time around, the new petals will be offset from the ones already there.  In a repeating scan, they would be a period after which the new petals align with ones that came before.
It's possible that the lidar has a lens (or combination of lenses) that transforms the scanning pattern, for example, by elongating the horizontal sweeps.  Looking at the pattern, there also seems to be a some (intentional?) "pin-cushion" distortion, which could be done with a lens system.  I'm not sure a lens system is necessary.  It may be possible to get that top-to-bottom narrowing by adding an extra term to g(t).
Livox's description says this is a multi-laser scanner.  My guess is that there are n slightly offset beams bouncing off the same reflector for more coverage in the same amount of time. That could account for the apparent bundles of loops.

Your answer is quite helpful and I have a starting point. Thnaks!
